# Call MVC Controller Method from TypeScript/JavaScript without jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript

Is it possible to call MVC Controller Method with Ajax call in Type Script/JavaScript without Jquery? if not How I can Call Controller Method from JavaScript/Type Script file?

Consider a method that is calling Controller method to sort and send a sort column to it:

This is function in ts file:

```
 function SortData()
  {
     .... call Controller method and send sortCriteria (FullName) to it

   }
```

and this is Controller method:

```
   [Route("sortbycolumn")]
    public ActionResult SortByColumn(string sortCriteria)
    {
       .... Do the sort retun back json result
    }
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest object - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included an example of a GET and a POST + submitting/receiving data using vanilla JS & AJAX below.

For further info, give [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) a read.

Good luck.

```
function SortData() {

    var data;

    //Post Example
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("POST", "/Controller/Action", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    //There are two options for using xhttp.send(): Only keep the ONE that applies to you

    //Option 1: Submit data to the server
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(params));

    //OR

    //Option 2: Nothing to submit to the server
    xhttp.send(); 

    xhttp.onload = function(response) {

        if(response.target.status == 200) {

            data = JSON.parse(response.target.response);

        }

     };

     //Get Example
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

     xhttp.open("GET", "/Controller/Action", true);
     xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    //There are two options for using xhttp.send(): Only keep the ONE that applies to you

    //Option 1: Submit data to the server
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(params));

    //OR

    //Option 2: Nothing to submit to the server
    xhttp.send();

     xhttp.onload = function(response) {

        if(response.target.status == 200) {

            data = JSON.parse(response.target.response);

        }

     };
}
```

Comment: I have this: function SortData() {  
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "Home/SortByColumn", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("sortCriteria=FullName");
    xhttp.send();
}   it is working and send the variable but I am getting this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED. in console

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are calling  xhttp.send(); twice. Once with the data to send, and once without parameters. In my example, I added a comment saying to use xhttp.send(params); if you had to submit something and to use xhttp.send(); if you didnt need to submit anything. Don't use both one after the other :) I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can. In fact, jQuery is library based on javascript and it is not an independent language. Here is what you have to do:

```
function SortData(){
  // Every ajax call is an XMLHttpRequest
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // It means that your request is processed asynchronously. 
  // So we need to define the method that has to be run once the response is received,
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    // status 200 means that your request has been processed successfully.

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // Change your html here
    }
  };
  // Setting your request
  xhttp.open("POST", "mycontroller/myaction", true);

  // Send your request when everything is set.
  xhttp.send();
}
```

If you need more to know, check out this link: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp